# Solving a seemingly-trivial trigonometric equation for a specific variable

Tags: abstract-algebra, trigonometry, periodic-functions, wolfram-alpha

I'd like to express $y$ in $y = \sin (x*y)$. I can get $x = \frac{\arcsin y} y $ without any issues and then kind of don't know how to continue. WolframAlpha seems to [have struggles](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%28y%3Dsin%28x*y%29%2Cy%29) with the equation as well — it doesn't return explicit results as usual. I wasn't able to find any similar problems online. Can anyone explain what's going on here or point me to some relevant literature please?

Comment: Why do you expect $x\mapsto \arcsin{(x)}/x$ to have an elementary inverse? Many functions don't. Also you will need to consider each branch of the arcsine if you want to use the latter equation.

Comment: I don't expect a simple solution. I thought at the first sight that I'll easily solve it and then realized that it's apparently more complicated. Now I'd like to learn more about the problem and cannot find any seemingly relevant information online and it crossed my mind that someone here could give me an advise on where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, there is no analytical solution and, as you wrote, the problem is simple from a computational point of view.

To obtain quite good approximations, you could build the $[2n,2n]$ Padé approximant $P_n(y)$ of $\frac{\sin ^{-1}(y)}{y}$  and solve for $y$ the equation
$$x=P_n(y)$$ which is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $y^2$.

The first decent one is $P_3(y)$.

You coul also expand $\frac{\sin ^{-1}(y)}{y}$ as a Taylor series around $y=0$ and use series reversion to get
$$y=t-\frac{9 t^3}{40}+\frac{969 t^5}{22400}-\frac{21197 t^7}{2688000}+\frac{3092997
   t^9}{2207744000}-\frac{1407584257 t^{11}}{5740134400000}+O\left(t^{13}\right)$$ where $t=\sqrt{6(x-1)}$